# Pull down in shopping cart allowing me to amend item quantity to up to five even if five items are not available

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am coding an online shop (not a real one). I can add to shopping cart no problem and amend the item quantity. However when adding to cart if less than five items are available then it does not give me the option to add more than what is available. However with the same for loop when amending the item quantity inside the cart, it allows me to add up to five of each item even if less than five are available. What do I need to do differently.

```
<form method="post" action="basket.php?action=update&productNumber=<?php echo $value["productNumber"]; ?>">    
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $value["item_name"]; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_brief_info" value="<?php echo $value["brief_item_info"]; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $value["product_price"]; ?>">
    <?php echo $value["item_quantity"]; ?>
    <select class="ml-2 pt-2 pb-2" name="quantity_wanted" class="form-control">
          <?php
              if ($value["item_quantity"] >= 5) {
                  for ($i = 1; $i <= $value["item_quantity"] - $value["item_quantity"] + 5; $i++) {
         ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
         <?php
                 }
              } else {
                 for ($i = 1; $i <= $value["item_quantity"]; $i++) {
         ?> <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>    
         <?php
             }
             }
         ?>
      </select>
   <input type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4" value="Update">
</form>
```

Comment: Are you serious with stuff like `$i <= $value["item_quantity"] - $value["item_quantity"] + 5`? You know that `x - x + 5` is just `5`, right?

Comment: That aside, I don’t really get your problem description. It looks like you would add options for 1 to 5, if more than 5 were still available, and only from 1 to how many are available, when that number is < 5. So where exactly is the problem now? Are those loops/conditions not working, and output weong options, or what?

Comment: check the brackets. you have one if, one else, should not have more than 4 brackets, you have 6

Comment: For example if only two items are available, inside the shopping cart it allows me to amend the quantity to above two. But outside the cart it is working fine

Comment: Have managed to fix the problem. Basically on a different page where I created the arrays to add to basket and update the basket. I had to declare an extra variable so that the database could get the total item quantity and the for loop could execute properly. But yeah found it strange how the same for loop worked perfectly when adding an item to the basket but now I know.